# Building a Scapy layer with a ShortField that contains BitFields

Tags: python, scapy

I'm building a custom layer in Scapy that has 4 bitfields

```
class TestProtocol(Packet):
    name = "TestPacket"
    fields_desc = [
        BitField("A", 0, size=4),
        BitField("B", 0, size=3),
        BitField("C", 0, size=1),
        BitField("D", 0, size=4)
    ]
```

However sometimes I want to send the packet in Little Endian order, sometimes in Network Order. So I'd like to create a ShortField in the layer that contains the BitFields.

Is it possible to define a field that contains other field types?

Thanks

Comment: I don't this this is possible easily. You should just make a copy of the packet called `LETestProtocol` and reverse the bits.. it's very uncommon to need to send both: usually protocols endian is defined in the RFC (almost everything uses Big endian, except 802.11 and Wireless protocols that tend to use Low endian)

Comment: @Cukic0d you're right, this is an uncommon situation. Its used in a test environment  where people can see what happens when packets are sent in different ways. Regardless I agree with your recommendation, thank you.

Comment: If you want to get a bit lore technical you can have a deeper look at the "Building packet with Scapy" section of the doc. You could implement your own `do_build` methods.. there are ways but it might get technical